# Dynamically created buttons won't fire until second click

Tags: asp.net, button, dynamic, click

I'm dynamically creating a table with many buttons on it. The goal is that every time I click a button, the button next to it changes its color. However every time I click a button the one I clicked changes its color. The one next to it will change its color only after the second click.

I am very new to this and my English is not so good, so if you could make your explanation as plain as possible that would be best.

Here's the code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table tavla = new Table(); //New Table
    tavla.GridLines = GridLines.Both; //Gridlines
    tavla.BorderWidth = 4; //BorderWidth
    tavla.ID = "tbl1"; //Table ID
    Button btn = null; //New Button
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        TableRow myline = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
        {

            TableCell ta = new TableCell();
            ta.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            btn = new Button();
            btn.Width = 40;
            btn.Height = 30;
            btn.ID = i.ToString() + j.ToString();

            btn.Text = btn.ID.ToString();
            if ((btn.ID == "54") || (btn.ID == "45"))
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.Black;
                btn.Text = btn.ID.ToString();
                btn.ForeColor = Color.Aqua;
            }
            else if ((btn.ID == "44") || (btn.ID == "55"))
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
                btn.Text = btn.ID.ToString();
                btn.ForeColor = Color.Aqua;
            }

            else
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                btn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(Checking);
            ta.Controls.Add(btn);
            myline.Cells.Add(ta);

        }

        tavla.Rows.Add(myline);
    }

    Panel1.Controls.Add(tavla);

}

protected void Checking(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button btn1 = sender as Button; // New button.
    btn1.ID = (int.Parse(btn1.ID) + 1).ToString(); // Button ID += 1
    btn1.BackColor = Color.Red; // Button changes color
    this.Label1.Text = btn1.ID.ToString(); //Label showing the ID of button clicked.

}
```

Final Outcome :
http://i50.tinypic.com/260frb9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the checking method, you are modifying the ID of the button you just clicked, which is wrong.

What you want is something like this (of the top of my head, there could be code mistakes):

```
protected void Checking(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button btn1 = sender as Button; // New button.
  string nextId = (int.Parse(btn1.ID) + 1).ToString();
  Button nextBtn = btn1.Parent.FindControl(nextId) as Button;
  //check here to make sure nextBtn is not null :)
  nextBtn.BackColor = Color.Red; // Button changes color
  this.Label1.Text = btn1.ID.ToString(); //Label showing the ID of button clicked.

 }
```

Comment: That's what I thought of too. But I don't understand why on second click next button changes color. Only clicked button should change colors.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! And for Peri, the goal is not really to color the next button, but coloring the next button is a way to get there. Anyways thank you rivarolle, you helped me a lot!.